# How to run maximum likelihood optimization (BFGS) in STAN?

Tags: r, stan, rstan

According to the [STAN homepage](http://mc-stan.org/), STAN is capable of penalized maximum likelihood (BFGS) optimization. I am using R package `rstan` but I haven't found any way how to use this method. I tried to look at the `?stan` help for the `stan()` function, but the only available options algorithms are `"NUTS"` and `"HMC"`.

I am using rstan version 2.5.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to look at `help(optimizing, package = "rstan")`, i.e. the `optimizing()` function in the RStan package.